# How does browser download image and other binary files?

Tags: http, browser

I want to know the exact mechanism behind the transfer of binary files using a browser. If the browser uses purely HTTP that means only text is allowed so the image is encoded using base64 and decoded later in browser? Or does the browser download this using some other mechanism where this encoding/decoding is not needed?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone wants to know the answer. While you can send the binary data over HTTP using base64 encoding, it is not the most efficient process, as encoding and decoding is required. So when you request an image file using http, the server gives you the metadata information such as MIME type, content-length etc. Using this information, the HTTP agent (eg. browser) actually downloads the image directly using TCP and not HTTP.